# How do you get a UserForm to activate on double click of a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I haven't been able to get this to work for a long time now after trying a lot of different things I've found online.

I am trying to get a UserForm called "UserComment" to open and activate when I double click a cell (within the columns of B-K and  and rows starting at 2 down to the last row of data) on a sheet called Open_Orders.

This is the code I have pasted into the Open_Orders sheet area (not a module).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng1 = Open_Orders.Cells(2, 2)
Set rng2 = Open_Orders.Cells(11 & Lastrow)
Set NewRng = .Range(rng1, rng2)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("NewRng")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        UserComment.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

When I click on a cell I get the error "Compile Error: Invalid of unqualified reference" and it highlights in blue the ".Range" section of where I set NewRng.

Any ideas of what I can do to fix this?

Also, this is a protected sheet with a password "maintenance"...not sure why there was no problem there.

EDIT: I have added the following code as the first line of code and I still get the same error:

```
Open_Orders.Protect Password:="maintenance", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

EDIT AGAIN: Gary's Student helped in the comments below by changing Range("NewRng") to to just NewRng....however it still doesn't work because it says its protected EVEN THOUGH I have that code above that should allow it to work.

*****UPDATE*****
For some reason, when I click the first row of data (row 2), it prompts for a password, and if I press cancel, then the correct userform pops up. No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with sous2817 above: it is going to be much easier to unprotect the *entire* sheet, and then re-protect it when the form unloads. Since you are displaying the form modally, the user cannot interact with the worksheet anyways, so that preserves enough "protection" -- when the form is modally displayed, the user can't edit it. So just unprotect the sheet, then show the form, then re-protect the sheet in the userform's `Terminate` event handler.

Here are a few additional observations:

This is a problem because you're doing string concatenation:

```
Set rng2 = Open_Orders.Cells(11 & Lastrow)
```

The result of `11 & LastRow` is not going to be what you expect. If `Lastrow` is "33" for example, the result of this expression will be `1133` which is an invalid range assignment. There simply is no such thing as `Range(11)` or `Range(1133)`, etc. (any numeric value like this will fail with the same error). Try this instead:

```
Set rng2 = Open_Orders.Cells(11, Lastrow)
```

Likewise, this is not a valid range:

```
Range("NewRng")
```

You have a *variable* called `NewRng` which **is** a range object.  When you do `"NewRng"` you're passing a literal string. Unless you actually also have a `Name` defined on your worksheet like this (highly unlikely), this will always raise an error because it's a non-existent range. Try this instead:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, NewRng) Is Nothing Then
```

I suggest you should read here about how to debug your code. Most of your problems are common mistakes that you will be able to resolve on your own.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Answer (score 3):

you need to qualify your .Range(rng1,rng2) with a sheet reference.  If you want the range to be the currently active sheet, then remove the . (dot) in front of .Range(rng1,rng2).

Comment: OK, I just tried both removing the . (dot) and I also tried putting it as Open_Orders.Range(rng1, rng2) and both times it gives me the error "Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' Failed" and highlights in yellow the "If not application.interesct..." line.

Comment: **If Not Application.Intersect(Target, NewRng) Is Nothing Then**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent That seemed to let it work, but it says it is a protected sheet so it won't let the userform open. Even though I have that line of code with the password and userinterfaceonly=true.

Comment: I find it's more reliable to completely unprotect the sheet @ the start and reprotect at the end.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Set NewRng = Open_Oders.Range(rng1, rng2)
```

Comment: "Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' Failed" and highlights in yellow the "If not application.intersect..." line.